# Nginx Configuration wildcard first folder

Tags: nginx

I am struggling to get nginx conf to work the way we need it. 
Basically on the same domain we have many apps, each one in root folder. As the user installs apps it is not possible to know the name of the folders.

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }

location /myfiles {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /myfiles/index.php?$args /myfiles index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

If I specify the second folder, it makes app in myfiles work, URLs are resolving properly. If I do not then the main app tries to resolve the URL and it fails.

So I would like to have something like:

```
location /* {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /$folderrequested/index.php?$args /$folderrequested/index.php?q=$uri&$args;
    }
```

where * would be any root folder, for example myfiles, mycrm, myaccount, which would route the trafic to that folder.

Any suggestions and ideas welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Put all your app root directories in a parent directory.

```
server {
    listen .....;
    server_name ....;
    root /path/to/apps;
    index index.php index.html;

    location / {
    }

    location ~ \.php {
        fastcgi_pass localhost:8000;
    }
}
```

Bingo.